# Base64 decode a binary content with Groovy script

Tags: groovy, base64, soapui, decode, binary-data

I use following script to decode a Base64 coded binary content and put it into a string then write to file.

```
byte[] decoded = slurper.signatureValue.decodeBase64();
String sigValue = new String(decoded)

def path = context.expand('${Properties#outDir}') + context.expand('${Properties#fileName}')
def myFile = new File(path)
myFile.write(sigValue)
```

When I use `Notepad++` with [MIME tools plugin](https://github.com/npp-plugins/mimetools) to decode it and save it, output is different and not sure, what is difference caused by.

Comment: If it's binary content, why do you put it in a string? And you only mention different results, but you neither show the base64 string nor the different results.

Comment: @jps : I tired also this function: `myFile.bytes = decoded`, but result is not ok.
I have just copied Base64 string manually and decoded in Notepad++ and when I compare two files(yes, which are not human readable), I see some extra characters.

Comment: Do you have a simple example that reproduced the problem you're seeing?

Comment: @tim_yates : Using this tool: https://iamkate.com/code/binary-file-viewer/ difference is, that question marks are missing from file, which was saved by Groovy script.

Comment: I'll take that as a no then

Comment: Normally `new String(decoded, encoding)` should solve your problem where encoding you have to find out. For example it could be `"UTF-8"`

Comment: Unfortunately without example value and expected result it's not possible to help.

Comment: BTW, when you are writing to file you also could specify encoding - file holds bytes...

Comment: As you already noticed your self the error is `new String(decoded)`. Since `decoded` is binary data, trying to handle it as a String will always cause problems. Your best bet is to never get `String` involved and write `decoded` directly to the file (as you did in your self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code produces valid(same as Notepad++ plugin) value:

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(slurper.signatureValue);
myFile.bytes = decoded
```